# Product feeds import

Tags: 7, feeds, importing-exporting

I have a CSV of data which I am importing as Commerce-Products.

**The issue is the price data gets rounded up or down when loading the price field data from the CSV into the price field of commerce-product entities.**

For example, one CSV field has a price value of £71.89. I configure the price under **manage display** with the provided options and I get the following results:

- Raw Amount: £72
- Formatted Amount: £0.72
- Formatted Amount with components: £0.72

So, I need help in importing the price data exactly as it is in the CSV, please.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the property of CSV column.

Comment: @NikhilM: I don't know what you mean. Please explain

Comment: CSV column property or type like text, number etc ?

Comment: @NikhilM: hi, you are right. Removing the decimal place from the price data in the spreadsheet allows the import to take place correctly. PROVIDE AN ACTUAL ANSWER SO I CAN MARK IT CORRECT TO YOUR CREDIT

Comment: Okay answer added.. :) Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Convert Excel Data Types in the corresponding column.

Excel 2010

1. Click the File tab, Click Excel Options, Click Advanced.
2. In the Editing Options, verify that the AllowEditing directly in cells check box is selected. Click OK.
3. Double-click the cell you want to format, and then press ENTER.
4. Click the error button next to the cell, and then click Convert to Number on the shortcut menu

[How to convert text to numbers in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291047)